locally convex planar curve fulfills $\langle \gamma,\gamma''\rangle\leq 0$
Let $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ a planar curve that is of class $C^{1,1}$. Therefore, by Rademacher, $\gamma'' $ exists a.e. Additionally, $\gamma$ is locally convex with Respekt to 0, that is $\gamma(U)\subseteq \partial K$, where $K$ is a convex body and $U$ is a neighborhood of $t\in[a,b]$ and there exists a supporting Line at $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma(U)$ lies on the the Same Side as 0. I am struggling to prove that with those assumptions $\langle \gamma,\gamma''\rangle\leq 0$ holds. Can you assist me please?

This seems very false, even if $\gamma$ is globally convex. Take a circle with the origin far outside. And if you take two semicircles joined tangentially, the inner product is positive everywhere but the junction point.

Well I am sorry, I have left Out an important assumption. I will add It quickly
